# Modal no funciona

Tags: bootstrap

Estoy tratando de mostrar un modal al presionar un botón en aspx.net pero no funciona.
el codigo del botón es:

```
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

y el codigo html es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>sied.net</title>


  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,500,600,700,700i|Montserrat:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS File -->
    <link href="../css/indexstyle/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Libraries CSS Files -->

    <link href="../css/indexstyle/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/indexstyle/lib/animate/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/indexstyle/lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/indexstyle/lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/indexstyle/lib/lightbox/css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Main Stylesheet File -->
    <link href="../css/indexstyle/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>



    <form id="form1" runat="server">


        <div>
            <!--==========================
  Header
  ============================-->
  <header id="header">

    <div id="topbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="social-links">
          <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
          <a href="#" class="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="logo float-left">
        <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
        <h1 class="text-light"><a href="#intro" class="scrollto"><span>SIED</span></a></h1>
        <!-- <a href="#header" class="scrollto"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a> -->
      </div>

      <nav class="main-nav float-right d-none d-lg-block">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
          <li class="drop-down"><a href="">Drop Down</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 1</a></li>
              <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Drop Down 2</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 5</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#footer">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav><!-- .main-nav -->

    </div>
  </header><!-- #header -->

  <!--==========================
    Intro Section
  ============================-->
  <section id="intro" class="clearfix">
    <div class="container d-flex h-100">
      <div class="row justify-content-center align-self-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 intro-info order-md-first order-last">
          <h2>Sistema Integrado<br>de Evaluación <span>Docente</span></h2>


<%--            parte del modal que no me funciona--%>

            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>







        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 intro-img order-md-last order-first">
          <img src="../css/indexstyle/img/intro-img.svg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section><!-- #intro -->


  <a href="#" class="back-to-top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
        </div>
    </form>




</body>
</html>
```

Al darle click al botón, no se muestra el modal.

Comment: Muy buenas, te recomendaría que editaras la pregunta y añadieses el código como `html` para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad y sea mas fácil ayudarte. Un saludo

Comment: que libreria usas para implementar el modal ?

Comment: Si revisas ejemplos de implementacion como ser: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp  estos funcionan, pero no tiene nada que ver C#. Revisa con el developer tools (al cual accedes con F12) que se esten cargando todos los .js de la libreria

Comment: No veo en tu código que cargues al final [las librerías de scripts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#js), recuerda que debes pegarlas antes de la etiqueta de cierre de tu body. Primero la librería jQuery y segundo la librería JS de Bootstrap. También noto que usas dos veces la hoja de estilos de Bootstrap, una normal y la otra minimizada. Revisa eso y nos cuentas